# Mobile drop down navbar

Tags: html, css, mobile, drop-down-menu

I cant figure out for the god of me how to get my navbar to show in mobile. I'm not using bootstrap since I already built my own style and when I use bootstrap it conflicts with what I have already made.

I'll paste the css of the menu im using and for mobile portion

```
    #cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #39b1cc;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #51bbd2), color-stop(100%, #2d97af));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 18px 25px 21px 25px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.12);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #d3eced;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #32a9c3;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 45px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #d3eced;
  right: 17px;
  top: 22px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 60px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  top: -4px;
  left: 20px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  top: 11px;
  left: -4px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul::after {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  left: auto;
  right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  top: 120px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  top: 52px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  padding-right: 6px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: 180px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 11px 25px;
  width: 180px;
  color: #777777;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #777777;
  right: 17px;
  top: 14px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #777777;
  right: auto;
  left: 17px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-left-color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-right-color: #333333;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

query for mobile

```
#cssmenu {
    background: #39b1cc;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    padding: 18px 25px 18px 25px;
    border-right: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #d3eced;
    padding: 18px 25px 18px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: url('images/bg.png');
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 45px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #d3eced;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d3eced;
    right: 25px;
    top: 18px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #d3eced;
    right: 25px;
    top: 28px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you want your navbar to be shown in mobile?

Comment: In the top left where they can click it to drop down so it doesnt take up the screen unless they need to navigate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it just with css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here's The Working [Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/vds5hd6d/)

And If you Want it to come down when you click you should use these codes in this [fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/vds5hd6d/1/)